# How to set access log file encoding in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I rotate access log of nginx every day. But I found that the file encoding is not always `utf-8`, sometime it is `latin1`  when I view the contents using vim. Is there a way to set the file encoding in nginx?

Comment: Afaik, nginx's log is strictly ascii, so it doesn't matter what your vim thinks

Answer (score 1):

You can reload a file in vim with the desired encoding.

```
e: ++enc=utf-8
```